# How to insert a button in the middle of a <hr>

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I basically have something like

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <hr>
  <button>
    <hr>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work, and I tried to style the hr too, don't work either.
I basically want a single line including a hr + a button + a hr, (so hr are about half size) all on the same line (row), all centered

Any tip ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flex: 1` on `hr`'s

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
hr {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <hr>
  <button>Button</button>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Update: If you want to change width on **hr** you can center it like this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/532/) also you can use pseudo elements instead [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/531/)